# 2017 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2017 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are. Please consider that current moderators [Matt](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/78/matt-lacey) and [Samuel](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/119/samuel-de-rycke) are not stepping down, and this election aims to elect a 3th moderator.

Please visit the official election page at

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).